# Возможен ли нестандарт в системном лотке?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Можно ли в принципе в системном лотке Windows создать пиктограмму (ну, которые через вызов `Shell_NotifyIcon`) нестандартного размера? Например, шириной как две (с отношением высоты к ширине 1:2)? Или (второй вариант) получить в системном лотке текст (как на часах), но, скажем, разноцветный (слово так, слово эдак)?

Если это в принципе возможно, то как?

Comment: Раньше такое было: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/band-objects#desk-bands

Comment: @user7860670 У меня не получилось - Windows 10

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Так в документации написано, что поддержку убрали в Windows 7. А в Windows 11 по идее теперь даже посредством установки хуков как-то модифицировать проводник стало затруднительно.